# Adding Bollinger Bands, TEMA Crossover and LRC all together in one script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add Bollinger Bands, TEMA Crossover and Linear Regression Channel in one script as a single overlay. I am encountering the following error on Tradingview -

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 34: Cannot call
> 'input.int' with argument 'defval'='close'. An argument of 'series
> float' type was used but a 'const int' is expected; line 36: Cannot
> call 'input.int' with argument 'defval'='2'. An argument of 'literal
> float' type was used but a 'const int' is expected Cannot call
> 'input.int' with argument 'minval'='0.1'. An argument of 'literal
> float' type was used but a 'const int' is expected Cannot call
> 'input.int' with argument 'step'='0.1'. An argument of 'literal float'
> type was used but a 'const int' is expected

My code is as follows -

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src_bb = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = ta.sma(src_bb, length)
dev_bb = mult * ta.stdev(src_bb, length)
upper = basis + dev_bb
lower = basis - dev_bb
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))

// TEMA
len1 = input.int(10, minval=1, title="Length 1")
len2 = input.int(20, minval=2, title="Length 2")
ema1 = ta.ema(close, len1)
ema11 = ta.ema(ema1, len1)
ema111 = ta.ema(ema11, len1)
tema1 = 3 * (ema1 - ema11) + ema111
ema2 = ta.ema(close, len2)
ema22 = ta.ema(ema2, len2)
ema222 = ta.ema(ema22, len2)
tema2 = 3 * (ema2 - ema22) + ema222
color_tema1 = color.new(color.black, 20)
color_tema2 = color.new(color.maroon, 20)
plot(tema1, color=color_tema1)
plot(tema2, color=color_tema2)


//LRC
src = input.int(defval = close, title = "Source")
len = input.int(defval = 100, title = "Length", minval = 10)
devlen = input.int(defval = 2., title = "Deviation", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)
extendit = input(defval = true, title = "Extend Lines")
showfibo = input(defval = false, title = "Show Fibonacci Levels")
showbroken = input(defval = true, title = "Show Broken Channel", inline = "brk")
brokencol = input(defval = color.blue, title = "", inline = "brk")
upcol = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Up/Down Trend Colors", inline = "trcols")
dncol = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "trcols")
widt = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Line Width")

var fibo_ratios = array.new_float(0)
var colors = array.new_color(2)
if barstate.isfirst
    array.unshift(colors, upcol)
    array.unshift(colors, dncol)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.236)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.382)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.618)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.786)


get_channel(src, len)=>
    mid = math.sum(src, len) / len
    slope = ta.linreg(src, len, 0) - ta.linreg(src, len, 1)
    intercept  = mid - slope * math.floor(len / 2) + ((1 - (len % 2)) / 2) * slope
    endy = intercept  + slope * (len - 1) 
    dev = 0.0
    for x = 0 to len - 1
        dev := dev + math.pow(src[x] - (slope * (len - x) + intercept), 2)
    dev := math.sqrt(dev/len)
    [intercept, endy, dev, slope]

[y1_, y2_, dev, slope] = get_channel(src, len)

outofchannel = (slope > 0 and close < y2_ - dev * devlen) ? 0 : (slope < 0 and close > y2_ + dev * devlen) ? 2 : -1

var reglines = array.new_line(3)
var fibolines = array.new_line(4)
for x = 0 to 2
    if not showbroken or outofchannel != x or nz(outofchannel[1], -1) != -1
        line.delete(array.get(reglines, x))
    else
        line.set_color(array.get(reglines, x), color = brokencol)
        line.set_width(array.get(reglines, x), width = 2)
        line.set_style(array.get(reglines, x), style = line.style_dotted)
        line.set_extend(array.get(reglines, x), extend = extend.none)
    
    array.set(reglines, x,
              line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                       y1 = y1_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1), 
                       x2 = bar_index, 
                       y2 = y2_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1),
                       color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                       style =  x % 2 == 1 ? line.style_solid : line.style_dashed,
                       width = widt,
                       extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
if showfibo
    for x = 0 to 3
        line.delete(array.get(fibolines, x))
        array.set(fibolines, x, 
                  line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                           y1 = y1_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), 
                           x2 = bar_index, 
                           y2 = y2_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x),
                           color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                           style =  line.style_dotted,
                           width = widt,
                           extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
    
var label sidelab = label.new(x = bar_index - (len - 1), y = y1_, text = "S",  size = size.large)
txt = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? "⇑" : "⇗" : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? "⇓" : "⇘" : "⇒"
stl = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_upper_right : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? label.style_label_down :  label.style_label_lower_right : label.style_label_right
label.set_style(sidelab, stl)
label.set_text(sidelab, txt)
label.set_x(sidelab, bar_index - (len - 1))
label.set_y(sidelab, slope > 0 ? y1_ - dev * devlen : slope < 0 ? y1_ + dev * devlen : y1_)
label.set_color(sidelab, slope > 0 ? upcol : slope < 0 ? dncol : color.blue)

alertcondition(outofchannel, title='Channel Broken', message='Channel Broken')

// direction
trendisup = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope > 0
trendisdown = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope < 0
alertcondition(trendisup, title='Up trend', message='Up trend')
alertcondition(trendisdown, title='Down trend', message='Down trend')
```

I have managed to change few functions as per version 5 of pine script. I believe thorough editing is required, which is frankly beyond my skill set. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the source type inputs, you need to use the `input.source()` function.

You also have an issue here:

```
devlen = input.int(defval = 2., title = "Deviation", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)
```

You are using `float` numbers but calling `input.int()` function. You should call the `input.float()` instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src_bb = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = ta.sma(src_bb, length)
dev_bb = mult * ta.stdev(src_bb, length)
upper = basis + dev_bb
lower = basis - dev_bb
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))

// TEMA
len1 = input.int(10, minval=1, title="Length 1")
len2 = input.int(20, minval=2, title="Length 2")
ema1 = ta.ema(close, len1)
ema11 = ta.ema(ema1, len1)
ema111 = ta.ema(ema11, len1)
tema1 = 3 * (ema1 - ema11) + ema111
ema2 = ta.ema(close, len2)
ema22 = ta.ema(ema2, len2)
ema222 = ta.ema(ema22, len2)
tema2 = 3 * (ema2 - ema22) + ema222
color_tema1 = color.new(color.black, 20)
color_tema2 = color.new(color.maroon, 20)
plot(tema1, color=color_tema1)
plot(tema2, color=color_tema2)


//LRC
src = input.source(defval = close, title = "Source")
len = input.int(defval = 100, title = "Length", minval = 10)
devlen = input.float(defval = 2., title = "Deviation", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)
extendit = input(defval = true, title = "Extend Lines")
showfibo = input(defval = false, title = "Show Fibonacci Levels")
showbroken = input(defval = true, title = "Show Broken Channel", inline = "brk")
brokencol = input(defval = color.blue, title = "", inline = "brk")
upcol = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Up/Down Trend Colors", inline = "trcols")
dncol = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "trcols")
widt = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Line Width")

var fibo_ratios = array.new_float(0)
var colors = array.new_color(2)
if barstate.isfirst
    array.unshift(colors, upcol)
    array.unshift(colors, dncol)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.236)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.382)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.618)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.786)


get_channel(src, len)=>
    mid = math.sum(src, len) / len
    slope = ta.linreg(src, len, 0) - ta.linreg(src, len, 1)
    intercept  = mid - slope * math.floor(len / 2) + ((1 - (len % 2)) / 2) * slope
    endy = intercept  + slope * (len - 1) 
    dev = 0.0
    for x = 0 to len - 1
        dev := dev + math.pow(src[x] - (slope * (len - x) + intercept), 2)
    dev := math.sqrt(dev/len)
    [intercept, endy, dev, slope]

[y1_, y2_, dev, slope] = get_channel(src, len)

outofchannel = (slope > 0 and close < y2_ - dev * devlen) ? 0 : (slope < 0 and close > y2_ + dev * devlen) ? 2 : -1

var reglines = array.new_line(3)
var fibolines = array.new_line(4)
for x = 0 to 2
    if not showbroken or outofchannel != x or nz(outofchannel[1], -1) != -1
        line.delete(array.get(reglines, x))
    else
        line.set_color(array.get(reglines, x), color = brokencol)
        line.set_width(array.get(reglines, x), width = 2)
        line.set_style(array.get(reglines, x), style = line.style_dotted)
        line.set_extend(array.get(reglines, x), extend = extend.none)
    
    array.set(reglines, x,
              line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                       y1 = y1_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1), 
                       x2 = bar_index, 
                       y2 = y2_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1),
                       color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                       style =  x % 2 == 1 ? line.style_solid : line.style_dashed,
                       width = widt,
                       extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
if showfibo
    for x = 0 to 3
        line.delete(array.get(fibolines, x))
        array.set(fibolines, x, 
                  line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                           y1 = y1_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), 
                           x2 = bar_index, 
                           y2 = y2_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x),
                           color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                           style =  line.style_dotted,
                           width = widt,
                           extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
    
var label sidelab = label.new(x = bar_index - (len - 1), y = y1_, text = "S",  size = size.large)
txt = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? "⇑" : "⇗" : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? "⇓" : "⇘" : "⇒"
stl = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_upper_right : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? label.style_label_down :  label.style_label_lower_right : label.style_label_right
label.set_style(sidelab, stl)
label.set_text(sidelab, txt)
label.set_x(sidelab, bar_index - (len - 1))
label.set_y(sidelab, slope > 0 ? y1_ - dev * devlen : slope < 0 ? y1_ + dev * devlen : y1_)
label.set_color(sidelab, slope > 0 ? upcol : slope < 0 ? dncol : color.blue)

alertcondition(outofchannel, title='Channel Broken', message='Channel Broken')

// direction
trendisup = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope > 0
trendisdown = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope < 0
alertcondition(trendisup, title='Up trend', message='Up trend')
alertcondition(trendisdown, title='Down trend', message='Down trend')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am learning, and studying your edits are genuinely enriching. Your edited code is working like a charm. Thanks a lot. With honest gratitude and appreciation. Regards.

Comment: Hello @KrishnenduBhattacharyya, I see that you are new to Stackoverflow. I would like to kindly tell you that, when your question has an answer that you are satisfied with, it would be nice of you to accept it as an answer. By doing that, we would know that the question has an asnwer, so we do not need to visit the question again, and the person who answers you can get some reputation. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I didn't knew this. I will do so right away. Thanks & regards.